# Creating and Editing a UtilityMeter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have some functionality that allows the user to create a `Meter`, which counts your gas, water, and electricity usage.

A `Meter` has one or more `Counter` objects, which keeps track of your usage for a certain date via `CounterReading`.

Once a `Meter` is created, you can edit it by adding a new `Reading`.

This is the caller:

#### Create:

```
internal void CreateUtilityTransferButton_Click(Premise selectedPremise)
{
    var printUtilitiesWindow = new TransferUtilitiesWindow();
    if (selectedPremise != null)
        printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.SelectedTransferPremise = selectedPremise;
    if (printUtilitiesWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        PdfFiller filler = new PdfFiller();
        var documentType = printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.DocumentType;
        try
        {
            switch (documentType)
            {
                case UtilityDocumentType.Transfer:
                    filler.Fill(printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.Transfer);
                    break;
                case UtilityDocumentType.Connection:
                    filler.Fill(printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.Connection);
                    break;
                case UtilityDocumentType.Water:
                    filler.Fill(printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.Water);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Verkeerd documenttype gekozen");
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            var popup = new ErrorMessage(e);
            popup.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:

```
internal void EditMeterButton_Click(Meter _meter)
{
    if (_meter == null)
        return;

    var premise = _meter.Premise;
    var createMeterWindow = new CreateMeterWindow(_meter);
    if (createMeterWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var meter = createMeterWindow.CreateMeterViewModel.Meter;
        meter.AddReading(createMeterWindow.CreateMeterViewModel.NewReading);
        if (meter is DoubleElectricityMeter)
        {
            var doubleElectricityMeter = meter as DoubleElectricityMeter;
            doubleElectricityMeter.CounterNight.Readings.Add(createMeterWindow.CreateMeterViewModel.NewNightReading);
        }
        VivendaContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is my codebehind:

```
public partial class CreateMeterWindow : Window
{
    private CreateMeterViewModel _CreateMeterViewModel;

    public CreateMeterViewModel CreateMeterViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _CreateMeterViewModel;
        }
    }        
    public CreateMeterWindow()
    {
        _CreateMeterViewModel = new CreateMeterViewModel(this);
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _CreateMeterViewModel;
    }

    public CreateMeterWindow(Meter meter)
    {
        _CreateMeterViewModel = new CreateMeterViewModel(this, meter);
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _CreateMeterViewModel;
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _CreateMeterViewModel.OkButton_Click();
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _CreateMeterViewModel.CancelButton_Click();
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _CreateMeterViewModel.ComboBox_SelectionChanged();
    }
}
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class CreateMeterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Window _Window;
    private Meter _Meter;
    private CounterReading _Reading;
    private CounterReading _NightReading;
    private MeterType _MeterType;
    private Visibility _isDoubleMeterVisibleVisible = Visibility.Hidden;

    public Premise Premise { get; set; }

    public Meter Meter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Meter == null)
            {

            }
            return _Meter;
        }
        set
        {
            _Meter = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Meter");
        }
    }

    public CounterReading Reading
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Reading == null)
            {
                _Reading = new CounterReading();
            }
            return _Reading;
        }
        set
        {
            _Reading = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Reading");
        }
    }

    public CounterReading NightReading
    {
        get
        {
            if (_NightReading == null)
            {
                _NightReading = new CounterReading();
            }
            return _NightReading;
        }
        set
        {
            _NightReading = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NightReading");
        }
    }

    public MeterType MeterType
    {
        get
        {
            return _MeterType;
        }
        set
        {
            _MeterType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MeterType");
        }
    }

    public Visibility IsDoubleMeterVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _isDoubleMeterVisibleVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _isDoubleMeterVisibleVisible = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsDoubleMeterVisible");

        }
    }

    private bool _isEdit = false;

    public bool IsEdit
    {
        get { return _isEdit; }
        set { _isEdit = value; }
    }

    //Used for enabling / disabling controls.
    public bool IsNotEdit
    {
        get
        {
            return !IsEdit;
        }
    }

    public bool IsNightEdit
    {
        get { return _isEdit && (_Meter is DoubleElectricityMeter); }
    }

    private CounterReading _NewReading;

    public CounterReading NewReading
    {
        get
        {
            if (_NewReading == null)
            {
                _NewReading = new CounterReading();
            }
            return _NewReading;
        }
        set { _NewReading = value; }
    }

    private CounterReading _NewNightReading;

    public CounterReading NewNightReading
    {
        get
        {
            if (_NewNightReading == null)
            {
                _NewNightReading = new CounterReading();
            }
            return _NewNightReading;
        }
        set { _NewNightReading = value; }
    }


    public CreateMeterViewModel(Window window)
    {
        _Window = window;
    }

    public CreateMeterViewModel(Window window, Meter meter)
        : this(window)
    {
        IsEdit = true; // This is only called when we already have a created meter.
        _Meter = meter;
        _MeterType = meter.Type;
        Premise = meter.Premise;
        _Reading = meter.Counter.CurrentReading;
        IsDoubleMeterVisible = _Meter is DoubleElectricityMeter ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        if (_Meter is DoubleElectricityMeter)
        {
            _NightReading = (meter as DoubleElectricityMeter).CounterNight.CurrentReading;
        }
    }

    internal void CancelButton_Click()
    {
        _Window.DialogResult = false;
        _Window.Close();
    }

    internal void OkButton_Click()
    {
        _Window.DialogResult = true;
        _Window.Close();
    }

    internal void ComboBox_SelectionChanged()
    {
        if (IsEdit)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_MeterType != MeterType.Unknown)
        {
            var eanNumber = _Meter == null ? "" : _Meter.EANNumber;
            var meterNumber = _Meter == null ? "" : _Meter.MeterNumber;
            CreateMeter();
            if (Meter != null) Meter.EANNumber = eanNumber;
            if (Meter != null) Meter.MeterNumber = meterNumber;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Meter");
            IsDoubleMeterVisible = _Meter is DoubleElectricityMeter ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            Meter = null;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private void CreateMeter()
    {
        if (_MeterType != MeterType.Unknown)
        {
            try
            {
                _Meter = MeterFactory.Create(Premise, _MeterType);
            }
            catch (MeterTypeAlreadyExistsException e)
            {
                MeterType = MeterType.Unknown;
                var popup = new ErrorMessage(e);
                popup.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind this is my first serious C# / WPF project, so I'd appreciate any remarks or suggestions.

Comment: You can use `Expressions` or `CallerMemberName` (+ .net 4.5) for `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's less error prone.

Answer (score 4):

Here're my comments:

- You shouldn't mix conventions like in this method declaration:

  ```
  internal void EditMeterButton_Click(Meter _meter)
  ```

Lot's of people use the underscore `_` for private fields and it's confusing when used with a parameter name

- You shouldn't name a method like it was an event handler but it isn't:

  ```
  internal void ComboBox_SelectionChanged()
  ```

Name it accordingly to what it does like `UpdateMeters` or something (it's just an example, I cannot deduce exactly what it's purpose)

- You should name methods firing events with the `On`-prefix:

  ```
  public void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
  ```
- Try to keep one style when naming fields:

  ```
  private CounterReading _NewReading;
  private bool _isEdit = false;
  ```

  it would be better to apply camelCase naming to the first variable:

  ```
  private CounterReading _newReading;
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the `_meter` stuff, along with the `On` prefix and camelcasing my fields. The reason my method is named like an event handler, is because my codebehind just connects the event handling to my viewmodel.

Answer (score 3):

Some pointers about how to improve your code

> ```
> if (printUtilitiesWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
> ```

can be written more idiomatic like

```
if (printUtilitiesWindow.ShowDialog())
```

because `ShowDialog()` returns a boolean which can just be used as the condition for the `if`. There is no need to check `if (true == true)` or `if (false == true)`.

---

It seems (we neither know if the `Fill()` method of the `PdfFiller` nor if accessing the properties of the `printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel` will throw an `ArgumentException`) that the `try..catch` is superfluous. You can just show the `ErrorMessage` in the `default` of the `switch` like so

```
    PdfFiller filler = new PdfFiller();
    var documentType = printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.DocumentType;
    switch (documentType)
    {
        case UtilityDocumentType.Transfer:
            filler.Fill(printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.Transfer);
            break;
        case UtilityDocumentType.Connection:
            filler.Fill(printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.Connection);
            break;
        case UtilityDocumentType.Water:
            filler.Fill(printUtilitiesWindow.TransferUtilitiesWindowViewModel.Water);
            break;
        default:
            var popup = new ErrorMessage(e);
            popup.ShowDialog();
    }
```

---

> ```
> if (_meter == null)
>     return;
> ```

You really should use braces `{}` for single statement `if`'s. This will make your code less error prone. If you decide against using them you should stick to your style. Right now you are mixing them.

---

> ```
>     if (meter is DoubleElectricityMeter)
>     {
>         var doubleElectricityMeter = meter as DoubleElectricityMeter;
>         doubleElectricityMeter.CounterNight.Readings.Add(createMeterWindow.CreateMeterViewModel.NewNightReading);
>     }
> ```

Here using the `is` operator followed by the `as` will reduce the performance because it is double checking if the passed argument `meter` is castable as `DoubleElectricityMeter`.

A more idimatic way would be to rewrite it like so

```
    var doubleElectricityMeter = meter as DoubleElectricityMeter
    if (doubleElectricityMeter != null)
    {
       doubleElectricityMeter.CounterNight.Readings.Add(createMeterWindow.CreateMeterViewModel.NewNightReading);
    }
```

---

> ```
> public Meter Meter
> {
>     get
>     {
>         if (_Meter == null)
>         {
>
>         }
>         return _Meter;
>     }
>     set
>     {
>         _Meter = value;
>         NotifyPropertyChanged("Meter");
>     }
> }
> ```

Here I see two problems. The first is the superfluous check `if (_Meter == null)` which doesn't add anything to the code. You can just remove it.

The more important problem is that you never ever check if the passed in value really is different to the stored one. Each time any setter is called a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event is fired regardless **if the property really has changed**.

---

```
private bool _isEdit = false;

public bool IsEdit
{
    get { return _isEdit; }
    set { _isEdit = value; }
}
```

here you should just use autoimplemented properties like so

```
public bool IsEdit
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

and change the references from `_isEdit` to `IsEdit`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The reason I write `ShowDialog() == true` is because the return value for `ShowDialog` is a nullable bool. I've applied your other suggestions.